# Bash script to search and rename recursively

Tags: bash, scripting, ffmpeg, avi, mkv

I have a bash script that converts *.mkv files to *.avi files. Here's what it looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $(ls *mkv | sed ‘s/\(.*\)\..*/\1/’)
do
ffmpeg -i $f.mkv -sameq $f.avi
done
```

What I need this script to do however, is it needs to search recurssively in all folders for *.mkv files and then run the ffmpeg command and save the output to the same directory.

PLEASE can someone help me? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
find <file_path> -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%%.mkv}.avi"' {} \;
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a semicolon at the end.

Comment: You also seem to think that conversion from Matroska to AVI is a simple matter of a rename.

Comment: I would use two percent signs in the parameter expansion to make sure that you only remove the ".mkv" at the end. This protects against the rare case when ".mkv" might appear more than once in the name.

Comment: @Dennis, Not sure but went with the assumption that file name will be like somemkvfile.mkv.

Comment: @lanzz, frankly; no idea about `ffmpeg` command or `Matroska` (Heard that first time) but this is the simplest way ... renaming with `mv` command, that's what generally I do. So, suggested that.

Comment: It is the simplest way to rename a file. What @justinhartman is trying to do is to mass-convert video from one format to another.

Comment: @Rahul @lanzz this seems to work nicely using ffmpeg: `find /Users/justinhartman/Movies/Game\ of\ Thrones -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -sameq "${0%%.mkv}.avi"' {} \;`

Comment: @Rahul you're a star, thanks a million and thanks very much to everyone who commented on this post!

Answer (score 4):

```
find /some/path -name '*.mkv' | while read f
do
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -sameq "${f:0:-4}.avi"
done
```

Comment: Ugh. Never use sed to just replace an extension in a variable.

Comment: Ugh2. Never use a bashism when a POSIX solution does it :-) `${f%mkv}avi`. Thanks for listening; a rare trait these days... +1

Comment: pattern matching is a waste of cpu cycles where you already know that you need to strip a fixed number of chars, even if it is a bashism.

Comment: @lanzz I keep getting this output:

Comment: `Justins-MacBook:Desktop justinhartman$ sh mkv2avi.sh`
`mkv2avi.sh: line 4: -4: substring expression < 0`

Comment: Sorry, turns out to work only with more recent versions of `bash`. Change `${f:0:-4}.avi` to `${f%.mkv}.avi`. @Jens, it finally boils down to a POSIX solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*.mkv" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -sameq `basename {} .mkv`.avi \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Raul this is what worked for me and is the solution to what I wanted to do which is run recursively through directories and run the ffmpeg command on mkv files:

```
#!/bin/bash
find <file_path> -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -sameq "${0%%.mkv}.avi"' {} \;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ls *.mkv` use `find . -name "*.mkv"`.

This assumes no funny filenames (no spaces, newlines). Another possibility is using `find` in conjunction with `xargs`. The xargs manual makes for an instructive reading which will save your scripting life one day :-)

Comment: instead of `find ...` use `for f in *.mkv` -- then you don't have to care about funny filenames as long as you quote the variable.

Comment: But this does not do directory recursion, which is exactly the problem at hand.